# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6, react-native-screens

I started leaning react native and stuck at this issue:

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager.
```

I checked on react-native-screen and @react-navigation repositories but exact solution that solves the issue.

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
},
```

App.js

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Categories"
            screenOptions={{
                unmountOnBlur: true,
            }}>
            <Stack.Screen name='Categories' component={Categories} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: Did you reload the whole project including metro?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? @Varinder Sohal